# Selenium IDE - Get span attribute in a table

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

In this website I have to get the tooltip text of this element:

[image]

If I write xpath `//html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]` I get the `KWPH-48` text. Is there a way to get this tooltip text `Create a new OneDrive folder` ?

Answer (score 0):

try following using getAttribute() function:

```
 String toolTip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")).getAttribute("data-original-title");
```

Comment: It's Selenium IDE :-), I think your post is only valid for WebDriver right?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out finally:

```
Command: storeAttribute
Target: //html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span@data-original-title
Value: variableName
```